# Okta sessions/me returning 404 when called from Javascript (Redux)

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am trying to get the current session Object from Okta using the sessions/me endpoint called from Javascript (Redux action), but I get a not found response, even when I have an active session.

It's not CORS related, I enabled CORS for my domain.

The best I can tell is a cookie related issue. 
When I call sessions/me from the browser directly, I see the browser attaching multiple cookies to my request. 
When I call from javascript, there are no cookies attached to the request.

Is there a way, from Javascript to have access to the cookie needed for sessions/me to succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a 3rd party cookie issue:

https://blog.zok.pw/web/2015/10/21/3rd-party-cookies-in-practice/

For example, in Safari privacy settings, I am able to repro the 404 on sessions/me if I set "*Cookies and website data*" to "*Allow from current website only*". If I set it to "*Allow from websites I visit*", I no longer get the 404 and /sessions/me works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? Please see the following page to learn more about CORS and browsers supported: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors.html#browser-support