# Okta Widget NOT Rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget, okta

Currently, using 1.6.0 of the scripts and CSS files. I have the widget integrated in my Angular 1.5.x app. I have been experiencing issues receiving 404 when trying to render the OKTA Widget as its GET request to:

`https://*.oktapreview.com/api/v1/sessions/me`

Which means that the widget gets rendered once and I am able to log in, but once I log out, I am not able to re-render the widget without having to refresh the browser first.

Has anyone found and resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be related to [this Stack Overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603700/60406). Can you check your privacy settings?

The reason for this issue is because the widget exchanges the `sessionToken` (which you get after logging in) with an `id_token` via a hidden iframe, at which time the session cookie is also set. But, since this is in an `<iframe>`, it's considered a third-party cookie.

There is currently no good way around this when your browser has third-party cookies disabled without redirecting to Okta to set the session cookie. A new version (1.8.0) of the widget is going to be released this week will make this easier (See [this commmit](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget/commit/08e0336eed109e79d73155faefcfe8e22a9bbedd) which addresses this issue). With this new version, passing in [authParams.display = 'page'](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget#openid-connect) will perform the call to `/authorize` via a redirect rather than through the hidden iframe.

Comment: I am glad this will be addressed in the subsequent release. I wouldn't want to tell every user to make this change in their browser. When should I expect this release?

Comment: It's been published and is [available on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-signin-widget) now, and will roll out to our production CDN in about a week and a half (after going through oktapreview, etc).

Comment: Ok, I see that 1.8.0 is now available via CDN. Where can I find sample of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Now that 1.8.0 is available via Okta's CDN, here is a sample of how to use the `authParams.display = 'page'` setting described above:

```
  <script>
    var config = {
      baseUrl: 'https://YOUR-OKTA-ORG-HERE.okta.com',
      clientId: 'YOUR-OKTA-CLIENT-ID-HERE',
      redirectUri: 'YOUR-REDIRECT-URL-HERE',
      authParams: {
        responseType: 'code',
        display: 'page',
        scopes: ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
      }
    };
    var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn(config);

    oktaSignIn.renderEl({ el: '#app-container' }, () => {});
  </script>
```

Comment: so the responseType is now **code** and no longer **id_token**?

Comment: I have tried the same code as mentioned above. I am getting 302 warning message.